# How to detect tinyMCE textarea blur/focusout event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am working on existing project. When I click some editable text on webpage, it becomes textarea and tinyMCE tool bar appears. When I click outside that textarea then toolbar disappears. I want to get that event when textarea lost focus and want to submit the form automatically.

I am unable to capture that `focusout` event. Only `mouseout` event is working but it is not good because as we move outside textarea, form is submitted  and page is refreshed each time.

```
$('.module-container form').live("mouseout", function() { // blur/focusout not working here. even ".module-container form textarea" selector not working
    alert('outside');
});
```

So how to capture tinyMCE textarea `focusout` event. Any Idea ?

Thanks

Comment: So you can actually get rid of the instance of the editor?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tinyMCE.dom.Event.add(tinyMCE.getInstanceById("editor-id").getWin(), "blur", function(){
    // Blur operations
});
```

Comment: I can see `iframe` tag in html when tinyMCE toolbar appears.

Comment: @Student Yes, if you aren't using MCE4's inline mode (http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php)

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach is

```
$(ed.getDoc()).bind("blur", function(e){
    // do whatever you like here
}, true);
```